# Find volume of a translated and rotated ellipsoid below xy (horizontal) plane

Tags: geometry, regions

I am trying to find the volume of the lower part (above horizontal plane) of an ellipsoid that is clipped by the horizontal (or x-y) plane. This ellipsoid is also translated (i.e. origin is not at (0,0)) and is rotated by theta degrees.

Im thinking of doing this:

`NVolume[p_,abc_]:=Volume[RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[{x,y,z}.N[p]<0,{x,y,z}],Ellipsoid[{xc,yc,zc},N[abc]]]]`

Here:

p = normal of x-y plane = {0,0,1}

xc,yc,zc = center of ellipsoid

abc = semi-axes of ellipsoid.

I have a few questions regarding this
1) does my code describe the set up of my problem? especially regarding definition of `p`

2) How can I obtain an analytical solution -> i.e. obtain the volume in terms of a,b,c, xc,yc,zc, and rotation angle? I need this to set up the formula in excel

Would appreciate any help in the questions, thank you in advance.

Regards
Jeff

Comment: any one has any idea on this?